# uninitialized constant - loading class issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So, I got mailer `app/mailers/dynamic_mailer.rb` and model `app/models/email_message/outgoing.rb`. There is method:

```
class EmailMessage::Outgoing < EmailMessage
...
  def deliver_mail
     l = ::DynamicMailer.email_message(self).deliver!
     Rails.logger.info "SEND MAIL: #{l.inspect}"
     update_attribute(:received_at, Time.now)
  end
```

Locally (developement env) everything works fine. The problem occurs when I'm deploying app to server (staging env) and trying to send email form there. Delayed job prints:

```
[Worker(host:rdev pid:2279)] EmailMessage::Outgoing#send_email! 
  failed with NameError: uninitialized constant 
  EmailMessage::Outgoing::DynamicMailer - 11 failed attempts
```

It looks like a problem with loading classes on server. Removing double colons before class name fails.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Employing `::` to force use of the root namespace is sometimes required if Ruby is convinced that there's a class in the EmailMessage::Outgoing namespace that could otherwise be used, even if it's not actually there.

Comment: As you see, there is :: before class name. Anyway, with or without :: still occurs the same error.

Comment: You implied in your question that it only worked with the `::` present.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear enough. As I said before - the same problem occurs whenever I'm using :: before my class name or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to restart delayed job daemon.

You can do it with capistrano, by adding gem 'daemons' to your Gemfile and updating receipes like that: http://cmar.me/2011/02/21/delayed_job-with-rails-3-and-capistrano/

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify file with DynamicMailer obviously in file with your model like this `require 'app/mailers/dynamic_mailer.rb'`. Probably it can help to find necessary class.
Also I've noticed that in error message is mentioned `send_email!` method but you posted here `def deliver_mail` method. Whether I don't understand something or you're looking in wrong place.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe its not one of the best practices, but it often works when app got problem with loading classes. In my case, the problem was in capistrano - I forgot to restart delayed job deamon in my recipes.